# Lstm model predict float between 0 and 1 but i want int

Tags: python, keras, lstm

i created a lstm model to predict number of crimes in months. For each month I predict the number of crimes for the next month. The targets are values ​​greater than 1 (normally) but the model predictions are always between 0 and 1. I don't understand the problem.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(35, input_shape=(1, look_back)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=20, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
testPredict = model.predict(testX)
```

This is an example of predict with this model `[0.5402554, 0.56099564, 0.5612484, 0.56098187, 0.5609817]` but normally I should have something like this `[66.0, 20.0, 20.0, 10.0]`

Thanks for your help

Comment: This sounds like you did not train the model until convergence and a low loss, nothing prevents the model from outputting any value.

Comment: so I have to increase the number of epochs? 
Is there a way to tell the model the number range?

Comment: This is why outputs are also normalized, there is no way to "tell the model" what the range is.